# How integrate Zxing library into Android Studio project that is imported from Eclipse

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing

I have imported android Eclipse project into Android Studio. My application works fine in Android eclipse, But showing the Following error in Android Studio:

```
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\DecodeHandler.java
        Error:(99, 57) error: cannot find symbol method renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap()

D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\encode\QRCodeEncoder.java
    Error:(303, 46) error: cannot find symbol method getURL()
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\result\AddressBookResultHandler.java
    Error:(137, 33) error: cannot find symbol method getURL()
    Error:(192, 36) error: cannot find symbol method getURL()
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\share\AppPickerActivity.java
    Error:(66, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\share\BookmarkPickerActivity.java
    Error:(39, 14) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    Error:(40, 14) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    Error:(55, 48) error: cannot find symbol variable BOOKMARKS_URI
    Error:(71, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    Error:(72, 30) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\google\zxing\client\android\share\ShareActivity.java
    Error:(145, 58) error: cannot find symbol variable BookmarkColumns
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\mobileinvoicesignaturecs\controller\MapActivity.java
    Error:(41, 31) error: cannot find symbol method getMap()
    D:\WorkingFolder\MobileInvoiceSignatureCS\app\src\main\java\com\mobileinvoicesignaturecs\controller\Themes.java
    Error:(113, 36) error: cannot find symbol class BaseAdapter
    Error:(48, 13) error: no suitable method found for setAdapter(Themes.ThemeAdapter)
    method AdapterView.setAdapter(ListAdapter) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; Themes.ThemeAdapter cannot be converted to ListAdapter)
    method AbsListView.setAdapter(ListAdapter) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; Themes.ThemeAdapter cannot be converted to ListAdapter)
    method GridView.setAdapter(ListAdapter) is not applicable
    (argument mismatch; Themes.ThemeAdapter cannot be converted to [![enter image description here][1]][1]ListAdapter)
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBGHN.png
```

Answer (score 0):

add following dependency in your build.gradle file @ app level.

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
```

hit Sync in Tools->Android->Sync Project with gradle Files.

Comment: Nope.. Added the above line.. Still ends up with the same error

Comment: renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap() this method is not a part of zxing dependency, make sure you have a different error, check  renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap() this method in your project at somewhere you have called and do not specified,

Comment: This same project working correctly in Eclipse. While importing this Eclipse project into Android Studio am facing this issue.